# How to save JavaScript generate value into mysql? [Laravel]

Tags: laravel

I made contact form in Laravel.
some of input field are just normal input field.
And rest of them are JS generate data which are 'product', 'quantity' and 'price'.
I can store ONLY normal input field data.

Here is my dd() image.

[image]

And this is my blade file.

```
<select id="product" name="product" onchange="caliculate()"></select>
<input id="v_product" type="hidden" name="product">
```

Controller

```
//Store data in database
Contact::create($request->all());
```

Could you teach me how to store product, quantity and price data into Mysql please?

Comment: Use different `name` attributes for your fields

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Sorry I'm still don't get it. Could you teach me code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude the other fields when getting request parameters, you can do the following:

```
Contact::create($request->only(['product', 'quantity', 'price']));
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I would like to store all data. but somehow I can't store 'product', 'quantity', 'price' .

Comment: @bluetail Are they added to fillable array in Contact model?

Comment: OMG! I totally forgot that! Sorry!!! It worked! Thank you so much!